# Running into syntax errors when trying to simulate a data set using the rnorm function

Tags: r, loops, apply, data-generation

I am doing a research project that involves me studying weight gain on 50 different groups of lab rats. Every week I am recording the mean weight and also the standard deviation of the weight for each group of rats. Currently, I have 15 weeks' worth of data for 4 groups of rats, however, I need 15 weeks' worth of data for all 50 groups of rats. (I receive 4 new groups of rats every 15 weeks).

For my research, I have recorded my weekly data into two different data frames. Data frame 1 is the Mean_Weight df for each rat group, and looks something like this:

```r
Mean_Data <- data.frame( Group_1 = runif(15), Group_2 = runif(15), 
    Group_3 = runif(15), Group_4 = runif(15) )
```

Data frame 2 is the STD_Weight df for each rat group, and looks something like this:

```r
STD_Data <- data.frame( Group_1 = runif(15), Group_2 = runif(15), 
    Group_3 = runif(15), Group_4 = runif(15) )
```

I am approaching a time crunch, and cannot afford to wait to obtain a complete data set, and therefore am trying to use the rnorm function to circumvent this inconvenience. To suit my needs, the syntax to use the rnorm function would look something like what is shown below:

```r
rnorm(50, mean= *, sd=*])
```

My issue is that I don't know how to properly code in the values for the mean and sd parameters in the rnomrm function. Ideally, I simply want to use the values from each cell in my Mean_Data and STD_Data dfs. Upon completion, it would look something like this:

```r
rnorm(50, mean= Mean_Data[1,1], sd=STD_Data[1,1]) 
rnorm(50, mean= Mean_Data[1,2], sd=STD_Data[1,2]) 
rnorm(50, mean= Mean_Data[1,3], sd=STD_Data[1,3]) 
rnorm(50, mean= Mean_Data[1,4], sd=STD_Data[1,4]) 
.
.
.
 rnorm(50, mean= Mean_Data[15,4], sd=STD_Data[15,4])
```

Could someone assist me with writing some sort of looping or apply function, so that I don't manually have to enter in the mean and sd values into the mean and sd parameter values of each rnorm function?

Comment: So you want to generate 15 vectors per `Group_*`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a double `Map` one-liner.

```
rand_list <- Map(function(M, S) {do.call(cbind, Map(function(m, s) rnorm(50, m, s), M, S))}, Mean_Data, STD_Data)

str(rand_list)
#List of 4
# $ Group_1: num [1:50, 1:15] 0.452 0.447 0.461 0.433 0.457 ...
# $ Group_2: num [1:50, 1:15] -0.3543 0.6925 -0.0813 -0.3047 0.6171 ...
# $ Group_3: num [1:50, 1:15] -0.2151 -0.18883 0.00794 0.04713 0.05671 ...
# $ Group_4: num [1:50, 1:15] 0.911 0.573 0.927 0.626 0.892 ...
```

The list members can be accessed by any of

```
rand_list$Group_1
rand_list[["Group_1"]]
rand_list[[1]]
```

---

#### Data creation code

The following sets the RNG seed prior to creating the mean and sd data sets.

```
set.seed(2021)    # Make the results reproducible
Mean_Data <- data.frame( Group_1 = runif(15), Group_2 = runif(15), 
                         Group_3 = runif(15), Group_4 = runif(15) )
STD_Data <- data.frame( Group_1 = runif(15), Group_2 = runif(15), 
                        Group_3 = runif(15), Group_4 = runif(15) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

```
rnormList <- lapply(names(Mean_Data), function(groupdId) {
  lapply(1:NROW(Mean_Data), function(k) {
    rnorm(n = 50, mean = Mean_Data[[groupdId]][k], sd = STD_Data[[groupdId]][k])
  })
})
```

To know what is what, you can also add names like

```
rnormList <- setNames(lapply(names(Mean_Data), function(groupdId) {
  setNames(lapply(1:NROW(Mean_Data), function(k) {
    rnorm(n = 50, mean = Mean_Data[[groupdId]][k], sd = STD_Data[[groupdId]][k])
  }), paste0("mean=",Mean_Data[[groupdId]],",sd=",STD_Data[[groupdId]]))
}),names(Mean_Data))
```